# When writing a mobile app, is there way to have the app automatically download another specified app?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, mobile

I have an idea for a mobile app (call it My App) that would use QR codes. I won't go into the details, but because of the way it would be implemented, it would be a huge, huge benefit for the user not to have to install My App plus a QR scanning app. Too much crap to download. So before I decide to invest anymore thought into this idea, I'd like to know whether or not it would be possible to have the installation code do the following:

```
User downloads My App

My App checks to see if a QR scanner from a given list of possible scanners is already on the user's phone.

if Yes:

    Do nothing

else:

    Download and install a QR scanner (after prompting the user)
```

I have zero experience with mobile apps, either in development or usage, so sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: No this is not currently possible on the Iphone platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is no mechanism to install one application from another (besides loading the appropriate App Store), you can use the free (Apache License 2.0) library, [ZXing](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/), to embed QR code processing into your iOS and/or Android application.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Does that include the actual scanning with the camera as well?